# Unable to use es6 syntax in codepen

Tags: javascript, codepen

I want to try out some simple es6 javascript  in codepen. i have followed their suggested configuration according to their blog post:  https://blog.codepen.io/2015/05/19/babel-now-on-codepen-write-es6-javascript-and-react-jsx/

Here is the sample code:

```
const features = {
  'PLAN_CATEGORY_BASIC': {
    'BASIC',
    'STANDARD_SUPPORT',
  },
  'PLAN_CATEGORY_SUPER' : {
    'BASIC',
    'STANDARD_SUPPORT',
  },
 }

console.log(features);
```

However codepen flagged a syntax error

[image]

I don't think it is a valid error. How can I fix it?

Attached is my pen configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is simply syntactically incorrect:

Object literals must have `key:value` pairs or the short way of that using `identifier`, but it's not valid to pass a string literal there like

```
{'basic', 'standard'}
```

So you probably want arrays, or use a proper object literal syntax.